# Google Chrome Helper processes using a lot of memory on my Mac OS X machine

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, performance, memory-usage

I find in my activity monitor that I have around 10 Google Chrome helper processes and most of them use 300-400MB. On some questions I read, they say to change the plugins from run automatically to click to play but that doesn't work.

How do I lower the memory usage of the Google Chrome Helper processes?

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome Helper exposes internal processes to the OS and the activity monitor. They may be background tasks of installed extensions or even just websites that take the memory.

You can follow what memory and CPU usage your Chrome tasks use in Chrome’s built-in task-manager which you can access from the menu: “Window -> Task Manager.”

In my case closing the Tab (a very large merge request in gitlab) gave me back my 4GB which I was after.

Answer (score -1):

Open your Launchpad then click on Application Moniter. Then type in chromehelper or chrome. Click on the proccess, then click the stop process button or the force quit. confirm your selection, then reboot your computer by clicking the  symbol and clicking shut down. Power on your computer, then open chrome. OR you can try unloading plugins from the Application itself. By clicking the options menu in the top right hand corner, try unloading uneeded extensions. The best option would to get rid of chrome completely, then just use Apple's Safari that comes preloaded on the computer it's self.

Comment: This is too short to merit an answer post and really should be a comment. Can you expand upon this and explain how this would address the problem?

Comment: At least explain the procedure to accomplish your suggestion.  Also, answers should be definitive solutions.  Helpful suggestions that may not solve the problem should be comments, which you need a little more rep for.

Comment: Fixed procedure.